# openstack object storage container content type

Tags: openstack

I'm a bit new to openstack container. I have a public openstack container,it's metadata is

```
Read ACL: .r:*,.rlistings
Write ACL:
Meta X-Container-Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Meta Web-Listings: true
Meta Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, GET, PUT, POST,OPTIONS,DELETE
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

When I copy my container url into chrome, i can see from the network tab, response content-type is text/html.
If I run a "curl -X GET -i ....." the response is also text/html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a>AA</a>
<a>BB</a>
</body>
</html>
```

However, if I do the same GET request from javascript using XMLHttpRequest, the response content-type is text/plain.There're no html tags in the response.

```
AA
BB
```

My javascript needs to extract all html anchor tags in the response so text/plain won't work.

I tried to change the container content-type both using curl and swift api but they don't work.

I'm not sure what is actually happening, is this a browser settings issue or object store container configuration problem..

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

(This answer came extremely late, as I wondered into this question by accident)

I am suspecting it is respective the [`Accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) header in the request.

Browsers would send `Accept: text/html`, which is why the returned response is HTML.

In JS, if you don't specify anything, `Accept: text/plain` is probably assumed to be the default, which is why you got the newline separated response.

If you insist on getting the html response, you could try the following:

```js
fetch(URL, {
  headers: {
    Accept: "text/html"
  }
})
```

Typically, JSON would be more programmatic friendly:

```js
fetch(URL, {
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json"
  }
})
```